# How to reference a resource created by a Terraform module

Tags: terraform

I'm using the [AWS VPC Terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/1.46.0) to create a VPC. Additionally, I want to create and attach an Internet Gateway to this VPC using the [aws_internet_gateway resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/internet_gateway.html).

Here is my code:

```
module "vpc" "vpc_default" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "${var.env_name}-vpc-default"
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "vpc_default_igw" {
  vpc_id = "${vpc.vpc_default.id}"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.env_name}-vpc-igw-vpcDefault"
  }
}
```

When I run `terraform init`, I get the following error:

> Initializing modules...
>   - module.vpc
>
> Error: resource 'aws_internet_gateway.vpc_default_igw' config: unknown resource 'vpc.vpc_default' referenced in variable vpc.vpc_default.id

How can I reference a resource created by a Terraform module?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since you're using a module, you need to change the format of the reference slightly. [Module Outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) use the form `${module.<module name>.<output name>}`. It's also important to note, you can only reference values outputted from a module.

In your specific case, this would become `${module.vpc.vpc_id}` based on the [VPC Module's Outputs](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/outputs.tf).

Comment: `module.vpc.vpc_id` in 0.13

Comment: I used the output name of the module as the identifier of the value I needed... Thank you!